# How to make a query with a collection in the select statement (not in the where clause)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables.  The parent table (parent) has a one-to-many relation to child table.
The parent table (Pa_Projects_all) and the child pa_project_players
They are joined by person_id

Let's say I have a project (project_id = 1001)

```
Project Id Project Name      
1001       This is a project
```

The Project Players has

[image]

The query should have something like this

```
Select Project_Id, Person_id, Name
from Pa_projects_all a, Pa_project_players b
where a.person_id = b.person_id
and a.project_id = 1001;
```

The expected result is

[image]

```
Project Id Person Id  Name
1001        500       John Smith
            501       Peter Carpenter
            502       Steve Sun
```

Where the column Person Id and Name are what I think they should be a collection.

The query will go in a data definition for XML Publisher and the result will be in Excel.

So in Excel Column A = Project Id, Column B = Person ID, Column C = Name.
One row in Excel for the result.
in other words, one Excel row per project id.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have this report in the SQL*Plus then you can use the BREAK ON statement.

```
SQL> break on Project_Id
SQL> Select Project_Id, Person_id, Name
  2  from Pa_projects_all a, Pa_project_players b
  3  where a.person_id = b.person_id
  4  and a.project_id = 1001;
```

If you want to have it in any tool then you can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Project_Id END AS Project_Id, Person_id, Name FROM
(Select Project_Id, Person_id, Name,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Project_Id ORDER BY Person_id) AS RN
from Pa_projects_all a, Pa_project_players b
where a.person_id = b.person_id
and a.project_id = 1001)
ORDER BY RN;
```